# Overlap bug in the next-privilege milestone pop-up message box

Tags: discussion, bug, design, user-interface

The "x" close-mark ***overlaps*** on the title of next-privilege milestone in the pop-up message box.

Here is how it looks:
[image]

Upon doing "inspect element", I found out that the CSS padding-right property was causing this issue. Here is the current CSS code:

```
.message.message-config .message-close {
padding: 2px 6px 3px 6px;
.
.
}
```

So, I changed the padding-right property value from 6px to 2px

```
  padding: 2px 2px 3px 6px;
```

and voila! Here it how looks now:
[image]

I know it's a very minor styling bug but fixing it does makes UI look better and clean. Also, in the above example, I used 2px value for the padding-right property as an example purpose but it might have other drawing implications somewhere else. I didn't experiment much. I would leave this to SE's UI/UX team for further experiment. On the side note, I have also put another feature request for [Changing the next-previlege milestone name and pop-up box title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260677/change-the-milestone-name-and-pop-up-message-box-title-for-the-established-user) and if that gets approved this will solve automatically (Please read PythonMaster's answer below for additional points).

**Tech-specs:** (just in case needed)

- Google Chrome Version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit)
- DELL U2312HM Display - 23-inch (1920 x 1080) - Intel Iris 1536 MB graphics (same result on 13" MacBook Pro retina screen)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late2013) - OS X Yosemite version 10.10.2
- Zoom-level - Standard at 100%

Answer (score -1):

I suppose this could implied as a very, very minor fix (like a little addition to the next update) but if [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260677/change-the-milestone-name-and-pop-up-message-box-title-for-the-established-user?lq=1) gets approved, we don't need to worry about this. But if not, I suppose it wouldn't hurt to change one little char in the code.

Comment: Yes I agree, I purposely did not put two feature-request/bug in this as I was burned alive before and told to stick one question per post.