# Change the milestone name and pop-up message box title for the "Established user" next-privilege

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, profile-page, privileges

Below is the screenshot of my [profile activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/254554/hackerkarma?tab=topactivity) that displays what the next-privilege milestone (*expanded to show pop-up message box*) I will be getting once I earn the 1000 reputation points.

> [image]

In the above screenshot, I have marked two places in the red. They are for displaying:

1. Next-privilege name (Top Red)
2. Pop-up title in the message box (Bottom Red)

As for next-privilege name (Top Red) goes, it should display the actual privilege name i.e. **Established user** instead of the current short description message. This little change would surely help the user to know the name of his next-privilege milestone.

Whereas, in the pop-up message box (Bottom Red), you can see that both i.e. "title" and "short description" looks very similar. It's kinda redundant. We should change the title by giving the official name of the milestone privilege i.e. "Established user" and leave the short description below as it is to avoid redundancy. The shorter pop-up title will also help fix the [**"x" close-mark overlap bug**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260674/overlap-bug-in-the-next-privilege-milestone-pop-up-message-box) (at least for this case).

Before this, I remember seeing "Create tags" and "Reduce ads" as the title for my next-privilege milestone. I can't reproduce it as the next-privilege does not allow you to choose the privilege (*just like how Badges do - gear icon*) to track. But, I did find another post where it shows a [screenshot for the Access moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253935/let-the-next-privilege-point-to-the-privilege-page-on-mobile) next-privilege which does validates (and also PythonMaster *answer* below) my feature request. You can refer to the [complete list of Privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges?tab=all) for more details.

So, if we follow the convention used for the all other next-privileges, then in that case, changing the next-privilege milestone name along with the pop-up title on message box to **Established user** surely makes sense.

Here is a **mock-up** that I have made:

> [image]

The above mock-up works very well as for the displaying name and title of the *one privilege* goes. But, there is one more *twist* here.

## Two privileges at the same reputation level:

The displaying name and title of the next-privilege gets complicated even further when user's are awarded *two* privileges at the same reputation level. Let me explain this by sharing the following screenshot:

> [image]

If you notice, now we have ***two*** privileges that are awarded at 1,000 reputation level i.e. "Established User" (milestone privilege) and the other "Create Gallery Chat Rooms" (communication privilege). The Privileges section of the Help Center also shows *[2,000 rep-level](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges?tab=all)* where it awards the multiple privileges to users. And, this is where it really gets complicated as we have so little space to display.

So, how should we display/implement this now?

If this gets implemented correctly, then it will automatically solve the display issue with other multiple privileges given at certain rep-level e.g. 2,000 reps. (or even for the future ones, if created).

Please share your thoughts, ideas or any suggestions. Also, it would be great if someone from SE's UI/UX design team could post a reply along with a possible mock-up for this.

**P.S.**

If this is implemented and it displays both privileges in the pop-up box, please *pluralize* the 'Next privilege' label above the progress bar.

Comment: You don't need to announce the date and time of your edits; they're recorded automatically in the post edit history

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this issue still occurring / is this request still valid?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, yes they should.

All other text in the `Next Privilege` box have the exact name of the new privilege as listed in the [Privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) section of the Help Center, not the description of the new privilege. It should be changed to your suggestion, though there should be some tweaks:

- Make the text in the box be in the center of the box

It stays the same no matter where the next privilege is (if you even have another one to earn). The new privilege name is centralized in the box. Keep the consistancy and it looks better.

- The description should be changed to: "See vote breakout (vote counts), expandable usercard

We usually call the vote breakout, vote counts. The extra info in the parentheses could help some users out about what vote counts are in the first place. But I suppose this could be optional, I mean it isn't that important...

**Edit:** With the complication from having two seperate privileges awarded at the same rep level, there could be a arrow button next to the text in the box that tells the user that there is another privilege. When hovered over, the tooltip should read:

> Click to see the other privilege that can be earned at 1k rep.

It is a little long though... The same could be used when the box has been clicked. The privilege overview could have another arrow button that when clicked, shows the overview of the next privilege.  The tooltip should be the same.

Comment: +1 Thanks for checking and confirming the Next-privilege milestone name.

Comment: I suggested edit to fix the missing end quote in the statement "See vote breakout .... but rejected. Since it was a small edit i.e. less than 6 chars,  I added link to vote breakout. Anyway, all I wanted to fix the end " Can you fix it, please.

Comment: I added the link to all Privileges (the page) instead. And sorry about rejecting your edit...

Comment: No problem... It made me little poor by 2 rep. points :) but please do fix that missing end quote as said in my above comment when you get time.

Comment: There is one more twist here and surely complicates this even further... Please read the EDIT section in my post.

Comment: That's a good suggestion... BTW, would it be possible for you to make your "Edit:" in BOLD face. It's hard to notice.

Comment: @HackerKarma  BTW, would it be possible for you and PythonMaster to [not put "Edit:" when editing a post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged)?

Comment: Sure I usually don't use Edit anyways

Comment: @1999 Sure... but what do you call this ADD-ON edit? Sometimes its hard to merge the additional details.. Any suggestion?

Comment: You could call it *Two privileges at the same reputation level* and make it a separate discussion point.

Comment: @1999 Sorry for the delay but I never received your notification... Anyway, that's an excellent suggestion you made. Let me edit my post. Thanks for the guidance.